# Ansible route53_zone doesn't create private and public hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-route53

I want to create two hosted zones 1 private and 1 public hosted zones. I have already created a vpc. Somehow when I run my ansible script it only creates 1 hosted zone. If the public zone task is first it will create a public zone and if the private zone task is first it will create a private zone only. I don't know if there is a bug in the module or I am doing something wrong.

```
    ---
    - name: Create private hosted Zone
      route53_zone:
      zone: "{{ private_hosted_zone_name }}" 
      state: present
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}" 
      vpc_region: "{{ vpc_region }}" 
      register: private_hosted_zone

    - name: Print private zone id
      debug:
      msg: "{{ private_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"       

   - name: Set private zone ID in a variable
     set_fact:
     private_zone_id: "{{ private_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"


  - name: Create public hosted Zone
    route53_zone:
    zone: "{{ public_hosted_zone_name }}"
    state: present
    register: public_hosted_zone


  - name: Print public zone id
    debug:
    msg: "{{ public_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"  

  - name: Set public zone ID in a variable
    set_fact:
    public_zone_id: "{{ public_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"
```

My code for hosted zone is here:

```
    ---
    - name: Create private hosted Zone
      route53_zone:
      zone: "{{ private_hosted_zone_name }}" 
      state: present
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}" 
      vpc_region: "{{ vpc_region }}" 
      register: private_hosted_zone

   - name: Print private zone id
     debug:
     msg: "{{ private_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"       

  - name: Set private zone ID in a variable
    set_fact:
    private_zone_id: "{{ private_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"


 - name: Create public hosted Zone
   route53_zone:
   zone: "{{ public_hosted_zone_name }}"
   state: present
   register: public_hosted_zone


- name: Print public zone id
  debug:
   msg: "{{ public_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"
```

- name: Set public zone ID in a variable
     set_fact:
     public_zone_id: "{{ public_hosted_zone.set.zone_id }}"

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by upgrading Ansible from version 2.3 to version 2.4.  Hope this will help someone else too.

Answer (score -1):

I think there’s an issue with your yaml. I’d use yamllint to make sure it’s standard then try again. Notably, your indentations look inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with the yml standard.  If there were it would have thrown an error.  The indentations look incorrect because of copy paste.